# How to allow the block content of the active X controls in a web browser control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser, activex

I am working in visual studio 2010 creating a userControl which contents a webBrowser. This webBrowser navigates to a html file which is inside the project. The html imports the jQueryUI   among other scripts and displays a popUp of this library.

I get the next problem: "*to help protect you security, your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access  your computer*"

And the popUp does not display. I have tried with the *Mark of the web* but it does not work and I have no more ideas.

Comment: please show us your code, and where you get the error so we can help you

Comment: I think there is no errors in the code just the problem with the visual studio because if I display the html in Internet Explorer 9 (with no security restriction) there is no problem but there is with the internal browser of visual studio 

thank you Philip